# How to get reference to the iframe that posted given message?

Tags: javascript, postmessage

Main window is receiving messages from iframes nested inside it.

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
 alert(e.data);
}, true);
```

How I can know from which DOM element the message has come ? The thing is that I have several of them in the document and all of them are from the same domain, but different domain from main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Firefox implementation of the message passing code (and maybe others), the event object has "uri" and "domain" properties you can examine, and a "source" property that refers to the originating `window` object.

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
    var frames = window.frames;
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i)
        if (frames[i] === e.source) {
            // found it ...
        }
}
```

Comment: I think chrome has a long lasting bug with this thing, the source property is undefined.

Comment: Yep, just confirmed it with 13.0.767.1.dev-m . With this bug the whole idea of sending messages looses its meaning.

Comment: Well, you can still check the domain and URI, plus there's nothing stopping the other windows from passing a reference to themselves (or an identifier or whatever) in the event data.

Comment: I just checked in Safari in iOS 14, Firefox 85, and Chrome 89 - using the "source" property now seems to be a valid cross-browser technique to match an iframe up with an event